# JavaFX pass connection to my second window

Tags: javafx, netbeans-8

I need help with this javafx code. How can I pass my connect to my second window. I am not using fxml.

here is my is my connection for my login scene and I want to pass it to my second window.

```
public class LoginStage extends Application {
    GiantsMainStage giantsM = new GiantsMainStage();

    private BorderPane boarderPane;
    private HBox hb, hbs;
    private Connection connect = null;
    private Statement stmt = null;
    private boolean userPass, connected;


    private TextField dbName, sName;
    private PasswordField password;
    private ComboBox<String> serverType;

    private Button loginB, clear;
    public Button clearSAF, search, submit;
    private Label dbNL, sNameL, sPassL;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage loginStage) {

        boarderPane = new BorderPane();

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(12);


        dbName = new TextField();
        sName = new TextField();
        dbName.setPromptText("enter database name");
        sName.setPromptText("enter server name");

        password = new PasswordField();
        password.setPromptText("enter server password");

        loginB = new Button("Login");
        clear = new Button("Clear");
        loginB.setPrefWidth(100);
        clear.setPrefWidth(100);


        clearSAF = new Button("Clear");

        loginB.setOnAction((javafx.event.ActionEvent e) -> {

           if (connectCheck()) {
               loginStage.hide();
               giantsM.start(loginStage);
           }
        });
        Scene scene = new Scene(boarderPane);

        loginStage.setTitle("Giants Login");


    }

    public void closeConnection() {

        if (connect != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
                connect.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

            }
        }
    }

    public boolean connectCheck() {

        connected = false;

        String databaseName = dbName.getText().trim();
        String serverName = sName.getText().trim();
        String sreverpassword = password.getText().trim();

        int num = 0;

        switch (serverType.getValue()) {
            case "MySQL LOCAL":
                num = 1;
                break;
            case "MYSQL REMOTE":
                num = 2;
                break;
            case "SQL SERVER LOCAL":
                num = 3;
                break;
            case "SQL SERVER":
                num = 4;
                break;
            default:
        }

        if (connect == null) {
            connect = Connections.getconnect(num, databaseName, serverName, sreverpassword);
        }

        if (stmt == null) {
            try {
                stmt = connect.createStatement();
                connected = true;
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                Alert notify = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                notify.setTitle("Blank filed");
                notify.setHeaderText(null);
                notify.setContentText("Incorrect login.");
                connected = false;
            }
        }
        return connected;
    }

    private boolean isAllFieldFillup() {
        boolean allInfo;
        if (serverType.getValue().equals("server type") && dbName.getText().isEmpty()
                && sName.getText().isEmpty() && password.getText().isEmpty()) {
            Alert notify = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            notify.setTitle("Blank filed");
            notify.setHeaderText(null);
            notify.setContentText("You are missing some information.");
            notify.showAndWait();

            allInfo = false;
        }
        else {
            allInfo = true;
        }
        return allInfo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is the class I want to pass connection to:

```
public class GiantsMainStage extends Application {
    private Connection connect = null;
    private Statement stmt = null;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage mainStage) {

        mainPane = new BorderPane();
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();


        tableView.getColumns().addAll(rankCol, nameCol, posCol, schoolCol, ageCol, warCol);


        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        mainStage.setTitle("Giants Database");
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.setResizable(false);
        mainStage.show();

        mainPane.setId("mainPane");
        mainGrid.setId("mainGrid");
        separat.setId("separat");
        clearSAF.setId("clearSAF");

        clearSAF.setOnAction((javafx.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
            if (!rank.getText().isEmpty() || !fName.getText().isEmpty() || 
                    !position.getText().isEmpty() || !school.getText().isEmpty() || 
                    !age.getText().isEmpty() || !war.getText().isEmpty()) {
            rank.clear();
            fName.clear();
            position.clear();
            school.setText("");
            age.clear();
            war.clear();
            }
        });

        if (loginStage.connectCheck()) {
            System.out.println("Still connect");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider adding a setter to the `GiantsMainStage` class and using it! Also IMHO it's a bad idea to implement the functionality that is used independent from the application lifecycle in a class extending `Application`, since this class contains stuff that is not needed in this case, like the parameters (the only member you use is the `start` method which could be implemented without overriding the superclass method too). It also seems like you want to use the `Connection` instance which the class is incapable of creating itself, which makes launching `GiantsMainStage` by itself makes no sense.

Comment: To reiterate fabian's point, each application should have only one `Application` subclass (and one instance of that class). Make `GiantsMainStage` a regular class extending `Object` and define whatever methods you need; pass the connection to the constructor or to a setter method.

Comment: Why pass the connection. Why not close the old connection and start a new one once you open the new view? Also This is a lot smoother if you use try with resources.